# Infinite loop in python simple password program

Tags: python

My program only prints `"Access Granted"` if I type password correctly in first try `"Secret password request : "`. If I type correct password in other try, let's say second or sixth, it just repeats `"Acces Denied, try again : "` even if I type correct password. Any help how to fix that?

```
my_input = input(str("Secret password request : "))
my_input = my_input.lower()
password = "secret1379"
condition = my_input == password

if condition:
    print("Access granted")

while not condition:
    my_input = input("Acces Denied, try again : ")
    if condition:
        print("Access granted")
```

Comment: You never update `condition`.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you change `my_input` in the loop, doesn't mean `condition` will change. It will still compare the old `my_input` to `password`, so you will have to reassign `condition = my_input.lower() == password`.

Your code will work without this, but you can also remove the `if` in the loop and just `print("Access granted")` after, because the loop ends when `condition` becomes true.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
password = "secret1379"

find = False

while find == False:
    my_input = str(input("Secret password request : "))
    my_input = my_input.lower()
    if my_input == password:
        find = True
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand.